# need advice for a shooter game created in flash Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

I have created a shoot game and it compiles well but every time i run the test an error

"Warning: No libraries were linked as Runtime shared libraries (RSLs) because of your publish settings: AIR for Android
[SWF] alienshooter14.swf - 4132761 bytes after decompression"

appears and when I try to play the .fla file, all the components except the alien objects are running. I am attaching the script if you able to identify the problem. I do appreciate your help. Thank you

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

var btn_downIsDown:Boolean;
var btn_upIsDown:Boolean;
var KeyUp:Boolean;
var KeyDown:Boolean;
var Space:Boolean;

var score = 0;
var livesLost:Number = 3;

var gs:gunsound = new gunsound();
var ebs:ebulletsound = new ebulletsound();

btn_up.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,upDown);
btn_up.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,upUp);
btn_down.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,downUp);
btn_down.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,downDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyIsDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyIsUp);

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,pulse);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Gunpulse);
btn_fire.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,shoot);

function upDown(evt:MouseEvent){btn_upIsDown=true;}
function upUp(evt:MouseEvent){btn_upIsDown=false;}
function downDown(evt:MouseEvent){btn_downIsDown=true;}
function downUp(evt:MouseEvent){btn_downIsDown=false;}

function keyIsDown(evt:KeyboardEvent)
 {
    if(evt.keyCode==40) KeyDown=true;
    if(evt.keyCode==38) KeyUp=true;
    if(evt.keyCode==32) Space=true;
 }

function keyIsUp(evt:KeyboardEvent)
 {
    if(evt.keyCode==40) KeyDown=false;
    if(evt.keyCode==38) KeyUp=false;
    if(evt.keyCode==32) Space=false;
}


function pulse(evt:Event)
{
    if (btn_upIsDown && !mc_gun.hitTestObject(tb_scores)) mc_gun.y-=5;
    if (btn_downIsDown && !mc_gun.hitTestObject(btn_down)) mc_gun.y+=5;
    if (btn_upIsDown && !mc_barrel.hitTestObject(tb_scores)) mc_barrel.y-=5;
    if (btn_downIsDown && !mc_barrel.hitTestObject(btn_down)) mc_barrel.y+=5;

    if (KeyUp)
    {   
        if (!mc_gun.hitTestObject(tb_scores)) {mc_gun.y-=5;}
        if (!mc_barrel.hitTestObject(tb_scores)) {mc_barrel.y-=5;}
        mc_barrel.y=mc_gun.y;

    }

    if (KeyDown)
    {
        if(KeyDown)
        if (!mc_gun.hitTestObject(btn_up)) {mc_gun.y+=5;}
        if (!mc_barrel.hitTestObject(btn_up)) {mc_barrel.y+=5;}
        mc_barrel.y=mc_gun.y;

    }

    if (Space)
    {
        if (bulletCounter<0) bulletCounter++;
        else bulletCounter=0;

        shootmc(bulletArray[bulletCounter]);  

        gs.play();
    }
    checkForHits();
 }



function checkForHits()
 {
    for (var i:Number=0; i<bulletArray.length; i++)
    for (var d:Number=0; d<numChildren; d++)
    {
        if (getChildAt(d) is enemybullet)
        {
            var ab:enemybullet = enemybullet(getChildAt(d));
            if (getChildAt(d).hitTestObject(mc_barrel) && ab.currentFrame==1)
            {
                mc_gun.gotoAndStop(mc_gun.currentFrame+1);
                ab.gotoAndStop(2);
                ab.visible = false
                livesLost-=1;
                ebs.play();
            }
            if (getChildAt(d).hitTestObject(bulletArray[i]) && ab.currentFrame==1)
            {
                var exp1:explosion1 = new explosion1();
                stage.addChild(exp1);
                exp1.x = ab.x;
                exp1.y = ab.y;
                bulletArray[i].x=-1000;
                ab.x=-1000;
            }
        }
    }
}

var bulletArray:Array = new Array();
bulletArray.push(mc_bullet1);
bulletArray.push(mc_bullet2);
bulletArray.push(mc_bullet3);
bulletArray.push(mc_bullet4);

var bulletCounter:Number = 0;

function Gunpulse(evt:Event)
{
    for(var i:Number=0; i<bulletArray.length; i++)
    {
        tb_lives.text = "" + livesLost;
        tb_scores.text = "" + score;

        if (mc_alien1.hitTestObject(bulletArray[i]))
        {
            bulletArray[i].y=-650;
            mc_alien1.y = 450;
            score+=20;
            mc_alien1.mySpeed();
        }
        if (mc_alien2.hitTestObject(bulletArray[i])) 
        {
            bulletArray[i].y=-650;
            score+=40;
            mc_alien2.y = 450;
            mc_alien2.mySpeed();
        }
        if (mc_alien3.hitTestObject(bulletArray[i])) 
        {  
            bulletArray[i].y=-650;
            score+=60;
            mc_alien3.y = 450;
            mc_alien3.mySpeed();
        }
        if (livesLost>=3) mc_gun.gotoAndStop(1);
        if (livesLost==2) mc_gun.gotoAndStop(2);
        if (livesLost==1) mc_gun.gotoAndStop(3);
        if (livesLost==0) endGame();

        return;
    }
}
function shoot(evt:MouseEvent)

{
    if (bulletCounter<3) bulletCounter++;
    else bulletCounter=0;

    shootmc(bulletArray[bulletCounter]);  

}

function shootmc(mc_gun:MovieClip)

{
    mc_gun.visible = true;
    mc_gun.x = mc_barrel.x;
    mc_gun.y = mc_barrel.y;
    mc_gun.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function endGame()
{   
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Gunpulse);
    btn_fire.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,shoot);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,pulse);
    mc_alien1.killMe();
    mc_alien2.killMe();
    mc_alien3.killMe();
    gotoAndStop(4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that:

> No libraries were linked as Runtime shared libraries (RSLs) because of your publish settings

so thats what you will have wrong.

One or more of your Classes need to be compiled as RLS like so -> [click here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/concept_runtime_library.html)

if the error is from your snippet, its one or more of these:

gunsound , ebulletsound ,  explosion1 (btw you should start Classnames with a capital, and your title doesn't address the problem)